Стриминг c низкой задержкой кадр за кадром ffmpeg
Я видел множество бибилиотек, реализовывающих кодирование видео покадрово, однако все они выполняют запись в файл, а не в Stream или хотя бы выдают закодированные данные байтами. Пара библиотек казалась перспективными, однако были на столько старыми что из них выпилили функционал ffmpeg. Какие вы можете посоветовать библиотеки которые могли бы реализовать кодирование видео в реальном времени покадрово для стриминга с низкой задержкой(не секунд 5 как я где то читал, из за каких то там I-frames)?

https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio можете брать пример

@aepot я тоже думал про это, однако это не c# библиотека с документацией, чтобы я в этом мог сейчас разобраться, какие там где вызовы ffmpeg-a происходят, какие не происходят...
